# INSERT only if both colomns are not duplicate

Tags: php, mysql

```
DELETE FROM RelationsAuthors WHERE MainId = :MainId AND AuthorId NOT IN (:authorarray)
```

The above code will delete anything that is not in `authorarry` and where `MainId` equals a specific value.

After the deletion I would like to insert the values of `authoarray` into the database if they do not exist without getting any errors.

*with using foreach `$_POST['AuthorId']`:

```
INSERT INTO RelationsAuthors (Id,MainId,AuthorId) VALUES('',:MainId,:AuthorId)
```

However I would like to add to my code that I need to INSERT only WHERE (MainId = :MainId AND AuthorId = :AuthorID) does not exist. How can I do that?

Comment: Wouldn't adding a "UNIQUE" together on those two columns suffice with an INSERT IGNORE

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, create a unique index on the two fields so the database will prevent duplicates for you:

```
create unique index idx_RelationsAuthors_MainId_AuthorId on RelationsAuthors(MainId, AuthorId);
```

Then the `insert` will fail with an error if you have duplicates.  You can have this error ignored in a few ways.  My preferred way is:

```
INSERT INTO RelationsAuthors (MainId, AuthorId)
     VALUES(:MainId, :AuthorId)
     ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE MainId = VALUES(MainId);
```

This will specifically ignore duplicate key errors, but other problems will still generate an error (if appropriate).  Note I removed the first column.  I'm guessing from the syntax that it is an auto-incremented id, so you don't need to include it in the `insert` statement at all.

Comment: `VALUES(MainId);` should be  `VALUES(:MainId);`?

Comment: @shnisaka . . . No.  `VALUES(MainId)` returns the value being assigned to `MainId`.  You could replace the expression with `:MainId`, but I find it easier to user `VALUES()`.